# An error 'Connection refused' occurred When I using maven to compile hadoop3.0.0beta1

Tags: maven, hadoop, compiler-errors

I try to compile hadoop3.0.0beta1 in ubuntu16.04, but when I running `mvn install` ,It prompt that:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from nexus-aliyun: http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/felix/maven-bundle-plugin/2.5.0/maven-bundle-plugin-2.5.0.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:jar:2.5.0 @ 
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-beta1 (/opt/new-hadoop/hadoop/hadoop-maven-plugins/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:jar:2.5.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:pom:2.5.0 from/to nexus-aliyun (http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public): Connect to archiva-maven-storage-prod.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com:80 [archiva-maven-storage-prod.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/49.7.22.49] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
```

It seems that I fail to connect to maven storage, but I try to ping this url and it prompt that:

```
PING tyjr-common-cn-beijing.aliyun.com (182.92.29.54) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 182.92.29.54: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5.51 ms
64 bytes from 182.92.29.54: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=5.92 ms
64 bytes from 182.92.29.54: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=5.93 ms
```

so I don't know why it happened.

I'm looking for your help, and Thank you again!

Comment: Why are you wanting to use a beta version? And just because you can ping a server doesn't mean you can access a webserver port hosted on it

Comment: It solved... It because of internet problem and I just change another wifi and it works well. Thank you for your help and you are right, ping a server do not mean that I can access it.